# Zabbix not display text on graphs

Tags: graph, zabbix, amazon-linux-2

I'm running zabbix 4 on EC2 Amazon Linux 2 instance. After last update:

```
May 29 08:06:46 Updated: zabbix-web-mysql-4.0.8-1.el7.noarch
May 29 08:06:46 Updated: zabbix-web-4.0.8-1.el7.noarch
May 29 08:06:46 Updated: zabbix-get-4.0.8-1.el7.x86_64
May 29 08:06:47 Updated: zabbix-server-mysql-4.0.8-1.el7.x86_64
May 29 08:06:47 Updated: zabbix-agent-4.0.8-1.el7.x86_64
```

All my dashboards graphs lost text description. Even in host configuration, when I click preview in graph there is no text. 
Checked on Chrome and Firefox. Tried to recreate dashboard, cleaned browser cache. I googled that it can be issue with fonts. Checked... Still not solved.

[screen_of_my_dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXYiF.png)

[screen_of_graph_preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKHqO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Resolved on my 4.2.2.

verify permissions for '/usr/share/zabbix/assets', if not 'www-data:www:data'

> chown www-data:www-data assets/

If the file does not exist (/usr/share/zabbix/fonts/graphfont.ttf):

> cd assets/fonts/

Copy the file graphfont.ttf to /usr/share/zabbix/assets/fonts/: (source: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-16182)

> cp /usr/share/zabbix/fonts/graphfont.ttf /usr/share/zabbix/assets/fonts/

Or link the file:

> ln -s /usr/share/zabbix/fonts/graphfont.ttf /usr/share/zabbix/assets/fonts/

by, Bruno Dolastro - Br4zil

Comment: Small change for Amazon Linux (RHEL/CentOS) with Apache:
`chown apache:apache assets/`

And damn misspelling... graphfont.ttf instead grapthfont.ttf...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with AlmaLinux and Zabbix 6.4
Obviously paths have been changed so simply the symbolic link for the font has to be renewed to get it working properly:

```
cd /etc/alternatives
rm zabbix-web-font
ln -s /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-sans-fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf zabbix-web-font
```

Then all grpahs have text and it's a lot easier to interpret things :)